# java keyboard shortuct capture dialog

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a plugin for netbeans and I want enable
the user to interactively configure the keyboard shortcuts.
Just like `JFileChooser`, is there something like `JKeyboardShortcutChooser` which
could somehow grab some unique identifier for the combination of keys in a form
that I could directly use while implementing the 
`keyPressed` method of the `java.awt.event.KeyListener`?
The GUI of `JKeyboardShortcutChooser` could be similar to the Tools | Options | Editor | Macros | SetShortcut interface of Netbeans (version 7.4).

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at the [jwindows](https://jwindows.java.net/) project.

Particurlaly, those classes that sound promising:

- [JShortcutChooser](https://java.net/projects/jwindows/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/jwindows/src/org/jdesktop/jwindows/explorer/JShortcutChooser.java?rev=790)
- [JShortcutNameChooser](https://java.net/projects/jwindows/sources/svn/content/trunk/src/jwindows/src/org/jdesktop/jwindows/explorer/JShortcutNameChooser.java?rev=790)